# How to make an image zooming to left hand side over hover effect using css?

Tags: javascript, css, html

am developing a simple image view and i want the image to zoom up to the left hand side when a user place up a mouser point. Current i have been able to make image zoom out but it goes to right by default. Here is my codes

```css
.imageDiv {
  position: static;
  height: 130px;
  width: 160px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.imageDiv:hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid #fed136;
  background-color: #b20000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageDiv">
  <img src="./img/images/mobilePhone.png">
</div>
```

please help

Comment: may be border issue on hover. please check

Comment: transform-origin

Comment: You could add negative margin to it: https://jsfiddle.net/g4z3tsou/1/

Comment: position: static is the default position if you don't set any position. So pretty useless to write it down.

Comment: thanks very much Danmoreng for the link, it is exaclty what i was looking for. I put (margin-left: -140px;) in my hover styling and its work perfectly